# XSLT: Solution for many tag with same name

Tags: xslt

I have an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>
            <title>Orange</title>
            <description> This is orange</description>
        </fruit>
        <fruit>
            <title>Apple</title>
            <description>This is apple</description>
        </fruit>
    </fruits>
</document>
```

How could I do if I want: 
If title = "Orange" ->

```
<P name="Orange">true</P>
```

else

```
<P name="Orange">false</P>.
```

Similar to Apple.
My solution is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document/fruits/fruit">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="title='Orange'">
            <P name="Orange">true</P>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <P name="Orange">false</P>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="title='Apple'">
            <P name="Apple">true</P>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <P name="Apple">false</P>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I receive:

```
<P name="Orange">true</P>
<P name="Apple">false</P>
<P name="Orange">false</P>
<P name="Apple">true</P>
```

This is duplicate two. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Please post a **complete** stylesheet. It looks like your `xsl:choose` is within an `xsl:for-each` - and that's why it repeats. -- And your test does not test the `title`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I has editted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are repeating the test for each fruit, so you get a separate result for each one of them.

If you want to test the existence of (at least one) Orange among **all** the `fruit` nodes, use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="document/fruits/fruit/title='Orange'">
                <P name="Orange">true</P>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <P name="Orange">false</P>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="document/fruits/fruit/title='Apple'">
                <P name="Apple">true</P>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <P name="Apple">false</P>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

or shortly:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="document/fruits/fruit" />
    <result>
        <P name="Orange">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fruit/title='Orange'"/>
        </P>
        <P name="Apple">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fruit/title='Apple'"/>
        </P>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks michael. You save my day ^^

Comment: I still have a question: In case we have more <fruit> tag, example 20. Do we need implements 20 <xsl:choose> tag or have a shortly solution?

Comment: @Devilguy I am not sure I understand your question. The tests above will work for any number of `fruit` nodes - but they only test for the existence of Orange and Apple.